# Is it possible to determine if a substance can dissolve in water just by looking at its chemical structure?

Tags: water

Is it possible to determine if a substance can dissolve in water just by looking at its chemical structure? For example, how am I supposed to know if $\ce{NaHCO3}$ and $\ce{Na2CO3}$ can dissolve in water or not? Or should I just memorize all of it?

Comment: No, but with experience you will start guessing whether the given compound will dissolve in water or not. At this stage learn the solubility rules. There are not many.

Comment: Adding to what @M.Farooq said, keep an eye out for exceptions eg Silver Fluoride, Lead Chloride, Sodium Bismuthate etc

Comment: Generally speaking, several thousands sodium and potassium compounds are known. They are all soluble in water. The only exception are rare : sodium bismuthate, sodium uranyl acetate, potassium perchlorate, potassium bitartrate, and may be some odd molecules, which remain exceptions. So please, just memorize that sodium and potassium compounds are soluble.

Comment: Yes. At least in practice and, as far organic compounds and different solvents are in scope, you don't have to memorize one by one. Note that this doesn't mean you always can or it is easy.